# Is there a way to validate that an unique identifier (IDFV or advertisingIdentifier) is not spoofed from server side?

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier

I'm writing a voting service through REST-API that accepts requests from iPhones but I want to make sure that each iPhone can only vote one on each question. Now from the client side I can get the IDFV and advertisingIdentifier. But when I send it to the server side, they looked just like random UUID. Is there way to validate that an IDFV or an advertisingIdentifier is not spoofed by attacker?

Comment: You could send the IDFV plus a hashed version of the IDFV.  On the server side you use the same hashing function and verify that the IDFV is valid.  This will be secure as long as your hashing function and keys remain secret- It will not defeat a determined attacker but will defeat a simple spoofing attack

Answer (score 0):

As noted above by `Paulw11`:

> You could send the IDFV plus a hashed version of the IDFV. On the server side you use the same hashing function and verify that the IDFV is valid. This will be secure as long as your hashing function and keys remain secret- It will not defeat a determined attacker but will defeat a simple spoofing attack